# Javascript prevent empty space before character

Tags: javascript, textbox, space

HTML:

```
<input id=MyTextBox type="text" onkeypress="MyFunction()" />
<input id=MyButton  type="button" onclick="Control()" />
```

**Onkeypress Javascript :**

I want to do below example , however i have not integrated according to **"MyTextBox"**

http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/9/

**There must not be no space before character in textbox.**

Comment: you mean to say there should be no space at all in textbox?

Comment: ________M  , before "M" there should not be space after i entered first character i want to use empty space

Comment: okay you mean first letter should not be space right?

Comment: Yes , it should never be empty space till character

Answer (score 0):

```
function Control() {
    var text = document.getElementById("MyTextBox").value;
    if (text.charAt(0)==" ") {
         alert("First Chart is space");   
    }
}
```

This works I have tested it

Also, to the left of jsfiddle, don't select "onDOMReady"

select no wrap in body

That's the problem why you get those errors

Comment: Also, at the left of the page you need to select "No wrap in body"

Comment: Don't select on DOM load

Answer (score 0):

TRY this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/2cYeu/18/)

For the first time space is not allowed later its allowed

```
function call(e) {
    if (document.getElementById('nospace').value.length == 0) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave this link http://jsfiddle.net/2cYeu/9/ in my subject.Problem is about integrating.I am not succesfull if i write code .

Comment: No , i just can not do it.Can you provide me code example according to above example ("MyTextBox")

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined , if i solve this , it will work in my opinion

Comment: if i write something to textbox